# How to set Chart Size in Android Using MPAAndroid

Tags: android, android-layout, highcharts, bar-chart

i am new in android. i have create Bar Chart Using this [Link](http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/learn-to-create-a-pie-chart-in-android-with-mpandroidchart/). but when i run my Emulator . it gives chart in very Small Size .

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Error Snapshot :[Link](http://tinypic.com/r/10wimfc/8)
Thanks for Help in advance

Comment: update snapshot as well with link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a Relative layout to store your chart? You can try to set the params of your main container to `fill_parent`, and set the params of your chart fixed or at `fill_parent`

I'm using a FrameLayout for that, but this a RelativeLayout with similar params it works as well.

This works for me:

```
<FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fl"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="210dp">

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
                    android:id="@+id/cl"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In this example the chart's height is fixed and the width is the width of your screen.

Comment: Since i used RelativeLayout that will match with Class Global variable Name like :private RelativeLayout mainLayout; so ur code dosent work for me .

Comment: Replace the frame by a relative then.  The params are important. It will work this way.

Comment: it doesn't work dear . mine layout is corrent but the problem with only chart it will appear on very small size . even i tried to set the size as well . but not worked

Comment: You are just inserting the chart into this layout? nothing else? Ensure that the relativelayout takes all the screen, and set a fixed size for your graph. it should work. If notm show me the rest of your xml because this is supposed to work properly.

Comment: Here is the full Code that i sued : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919683/classcast-expcetion-in-bar-char-using-mpandroidchart-jar/32926888?noredirect=1#comment53710576_32926888 .

Comment: This code is false, as an example you have the vertical param on your relative layout... change to Linear or remove it

Comment: are you talking about android:orientation ? . can you post the updated Code ? . That will help for me Thanks in advance for help

Comment: yes. This is for LinearLayout, I doubt you need it for RelativeLayout, and anyway not in this case

Comment: will you please suggest me how to do or can u update full Code . i am new on android

Comment: Try to use my layout instead of yours, framelayout is pretty efficient for a chart. then you have to programmatically add and fill your graph according to your parameters. This part happens in your fragment or your activity and depends on your datas, you can follow this link to begin: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki  . You can also try the code samples to get started. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

firstly Thanks to @Virthuss for help . i have created a frame layout on activity class ;

```
private FrameLayout mainLayout;
mainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
```

and on XML side. Called Frame Layout like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks a Lot once again for Help .